# PySide2 : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'objectName'

Tags: python, pyside, pyside2

How can I fix this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 32, in run_setup_turn_table

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'objectName'

```
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class mk_preview_UI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mk_preview_UI,self).__init__()
        
        self.UI()
        self.layout()
        self.show()
    def UI(self):
        self.setup_turnTable = QPushButton("Setup turn table")
        self.setup_turnTable.setObjectName("run_setup_btn")
        
    def layout(self):
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.setup_turnTable)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)



class run_ui:
    def __init__(self):
        self.MainWindow = mk_preview_UI()
        self.MainWindow.setup_turnTable.clicked.connect(self.run_setup_turn_table)

    def run_setup_turn_table(self):
        run_button = self.MainWindow.sender()
        if run_button.objectName() == "run_setup_btn":
           print "run_setup_btn"       
        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = run_ui()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This means that `run_button` is of type `NoneType`. Your issue is in `MainWindow.sender()`

Comment: It works fine when I set click signal in the 'mk_preview_UI' class:

Answer (score 0):

Note: Seems a PySide2 bug.

If a QObject emits the signal and invokes the method of another QObject then sender() of the receiver object will return the emitter object. In your case MainWindow is not the receiver so the sender() will not return the object that emits the signal. A workaround is to make run_ui a QObject and since the run_setup_turn_table method belongs to it, then the sender() will return the button.

```py
class run_ui(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.MainWindow = mk_preview_UI()
        self.MainWindow.setup_turnTable.clicked.connect(self.run_setup_turn_table)

    def run_setup_turn_table(self):
        run_button = self.sender()
        if run_button.objectName() == "run_setup_btn":
            print("run_setup_btn")
```

Comment: That's another interesting inconsistency, as in PyQt5 it works fine.

Comment: @musicamante Yes, I just checked. Another PySide2 bug

Comment: Your answer is enough , I thought It would be helpful to publish the full code .

Comment: @K4341 No, it does not help at all since: 1) it is just code without explaining, 2) it can be easily deduced from my answer.